# MDX query with count distinct filtered on another measure, that plays with other filters

Tags: ssas, mdx

in the SSAS AdventureWorks schema, I'm trying to figure out a distinct count of how many distinct customers have made Internet orders greater than $1000.

I attempted to make an MDX query like this, and it seems to *almost* work, except that new measure seems to ignore the slicer axis / `WHERE` condition, showing the count of customers for *all* countries, not just Australia:

```
With 
member [measures].[DistinctCustomersHighSales] as 
distinctcount(
   filter([Customer].[Full Name].Members, [Measures].[Internet Sales-Sales Amount] > 1000)
)
SELECT {
   [Measures].[Internet Sales-Sales Amount],
   [Measures].[DistinctCustomersHighSales]
    }
 on columns,
([Date].[Calendar Date].[Calendar Year].Members) on rows
FROM [Analysis Services Tutorial]
WHERE [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country-Region].[Australia]
```

What am I doing wrong?

If I were doing this in SQL, I would be looking for something like this

```
 SELECT Year(OrderDate) as year,
     sum(SalesAmount) 
     count(case when count(distinct case when SalesAmount > 1000 then dc.customerkey end)
 FROM dbo.FactInternetSales  fis
    join dbo.dimcustomer dc on fis.CustomerKey=dc.CustomerKey
    join dbo.DimGeography  dg on dc.GeographyKey=dg.GeographyKey
 WHERE EnglishCountryRegionName='Australia'
 GROUP BY year(OrderDate)
 ORDER BY year
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `EXISTING`:

```
With 
member [measures].[DistinctCustomersHighSales] as 
distinctcount(
   filter(EXISTING [Customer].[Full Name].Members, [Measures].[Internet Sales-Sales Amount] > 1000)
)
SELECT {
   [Measures].[Internet Sales-Sales Amount],
   [Measures].[DistinctCustomersHighSales]
    }
 on columns,
([Date].[Calendar Date].[Calendar Year].Members) on rows
FROM [Analysis Services Tutorial]
WHERE [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country-Region].[Australia]
```

Scope is a very important concept in MDX. Only when you add *`EXISTING`*, does the engine realize the slicer.

The initial set in the definition of member is :

```
[Customer].[Full Name].Members
```

Sets are static in MDX. So, this set by default contains ALL the customers. When you add an `EXISTING`, before forming the set, the context is checked. Based on the dimension usage(relationship) in your cube, it is able to filter the customers belonging to Australia. Thus it works.

Comment: That seemed to work.  I still don't understand *why* though.

Comment: @wrschneider added info

Comment: dam - beat me to it!!! ...EXISTING pulls the current context into the WITH clause